# SOAPConnection call throws exception

Tags: java, soap-client

There's a Web-Client application from www.webserviceX.NET to get weather data from SOAP-Server and it works perfectly. 
See here: `http://www.webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=12&WSID=56`
Now, I try my self to call weather data with Java SOAPConnection class, but I get an exception from this server.
My Environment is: jdk 1.8.0_45 and eclipse

## Exception-Message:

```
SOAPException: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. 
Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: 
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. 
Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown Source)
```

## What I send to server

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:GetWeather="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
<GetWeather:BlaBla>
<GetWeather:CountryName>Switzerland</GetWeather:CountryName>
<GetWeather:CityName>Zurich</GetWeather:CityName>
</GetWeather:BlaBla>
</env:Body>
```

## What the server expect

```
POST /globalweather.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.webservicex.net
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap12:Body>
    <GetWeather xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
        <CityName>string</CityName>
        <CountryName>string</CountryName>
    </GetWeather>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
```

## My Java-Source

This code throws the exception:

`SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);`

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            String url = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";

            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);

            SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();

            SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
            String serverURI = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";

            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("GetWeather", serverURI);

            SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
            SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("BlaBla", "GetWeather");

            soapBodyElem.addChildElement("CountryName", "GetWeather").addTextNode("Switzerland");       
            soapBodyElem.addChildElement("CityName", "GetWeather").addTextNode("Zurich");

            MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
            headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
            headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "BlaBla");

            soapMessage.saveChanges();
            soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            // call() throws a SOAPException 
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, url);   

            soapConnection.close();
        }
        catch (SOAPException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("SOAPException: " + ex.getMessage()); ;
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `url` that you calling:

```
String url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL";
```

With this change you will do proper call to WebService.